# extracting last n characters from a character column in r

Tags: r, dplyr, substr

I have a `data.frame` (let's say `x`) with a `character` column. I am trying to extract last `n` (let's say `3`) characters from that column and create a new column in the same `data.frame`. I am trying to do this:

```
library(dplyr)
x <- x %>% mutate(new_col=substr(old_col, nchar(old_col)-3+1, nchar(old_col)))
```

The error message:

> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) :    Evaluation error: 'nchar()'
>   requires a character vector.

I also tried this:

```
x <- x %>% mutate(new_col=substr(x$old_col, nchar(x$old_col)-3+1, nchar(x$old_col)))
```

Comment: Its probably a `factor` column. So use `as.character`.

Comment: Yes you are right. That is causing the issue. I will resolve it now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `as.character` inside `nchar` or use `stringsAsFactors = F` when creating the `data.frame`.

```
library(magrittr)
df <- data.frame(A = c("Blue", "Orange", "Black"), stringsAsFactors = F)
df %<>% mutate(B = substr(A, nchar(A)-3+1, nchar(A)))
df

       A   B
1   Blue lue
2 Orange nge
3  Black ack
```